# Shimano BR-T4000 not compatible with frame pivot stud

Tags: brakes, shimano, fork, replacement

I tired to replace v-brakes on my random cheap frame as spring regulation things started to fall apart. For replacement I picked front+rear set of Shimano BR-T4000 v-brakes because v-brakes are so simple and compatible with each other, right?

New vs five year old no-name part
[image: old vs new]

pivot boss/stud(?)
[image]

shallow hole (about half of old ones depth) in new brakes prevent them from fully setting in, which also causes that spring spike(?) to only go halfway in
 [image]

and stud is not reaching all the way through its slot (lacks ~5mm)
[image]

Fork is aluminium (or at least not reacting to magnets). Pivot stud is steel, but does not seem wrench-friendly as thick part is oval instead of segmented. Random old non-name v-brakes I somehow had on shelf are perfect match, and all around Internet I only see studs same as one I have.

Are new brakes broken/malformed/fake? Get another brakes? Use adapter part? Or should I just get new fork with replaceable studs?

Edit:

When compared with clean classic cheap v-brakes difference in depth is more visible:
[image]

Length of bore in oldies is ~2cm while new ones are ~2.5cm, wider part is respectively ~6mm vs ~3mm.

(yes yes, got new cables as well :)

Comment: What do you mean by 'shallow hole (about half of old ones depth) in new brakes'? The brake boss hole should be a constant diameter all the way through.

Comment: Did you get new mounting studs with the new brakes?

Comment: @mikes nope, no studs.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus there is wider part in hole to accommodate for wider part of stud in new brakes it is half as in old ones

Comment: OK, I see. Is the width of the new calipers more than the old?

Comment: Also, how far is the pin going in to the hole on the fork?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus pin is going in halfway

Comment: So where I was going with this was you may be OK as the boss does not need to go all the way through the caliper, but @Nathan Knutson beat me to it.

Comment: I found this problem difficult to understand initially. I did get my head round it after seeing the problem documented on a forum. I hope it helps someone (or at least it's acceptable) to [share the link here](https://www.bikeforums.net/20977241-post16.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is wrong here, just put the brake arms on and torque down the bolts. Your old brake arms are the type that pivot directly on the stud, and the new ones are the type that overhang the stud and have an integral pivot of their own. Use more torque than you would on the other type, because with integral pivots there's no risk of mushrooming the stud.

Comment: I will try again this weekend as having bike in pieces is a problem for daily commute, but I am still worried that recoil pin is only going in halfway. Isn't there some stress put on it by return mechanism?

Comment: @PTwr it gets some stress from the return spring but not tons. By all means, if it doesn't seem solid with the bolt torqued down then trust your instincts. But I don't suspect that's what you'll find.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty normal, though I'm not sure that you need more torque.

Comment: @Batman Cantis and v-brakes that pivot directly on the stud are notably low-torque items on bikes. A number out there on torque charts is 2 ft-lbs, very low, and the reason is the tips can be very sensitive to getting mushroomed with the bolt bearing down directly on them, an unusual fastener application. Whether going down to 2 ft-lbs is wise is another conversation, but one of the nice things about integral pivots is they sidestep the whole issue and let you put a more normal amount of torque on.

Comment: @NathanKnutson -  Didn't see "on the other type" -- I was assuming it would be about 5-7 Nm , which is about 5 ft-lbs of torque.

Comment: @PTwr did you end up fitting those brakes after all? I've ran into the exact same problem on [2016 Fairfax SC2 IG](https://www.marinbikes.com/gb/bikes/2016-fairfax-sc2-ig) + Shimano BR-T4000, and now considering what to do...

Comment: @abbot yes, it worked.